# Here-api. Upgrade to version 7 from 6. We use (RWS -> RW -> FIS->FI->TMC - DE ) in the xml file. Is it possible to get this data in version 7?

Tags: rest, here-api, traffic, here-traffic

The new version of the [here-api] api doesn't have this data and
the json file does not contain this data.
How does get this data?

Example responce version  6 and 7

[image: 1]

I tried to find a description of these fields in the documentation.
There are none for version api 7.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `tmc` to the parameters.
Here is a sample query

```
    https://data.traffic.hereapi.com/v7/flow?apiKey=YOUR_API_KEY&in=bbox:-80,39.19838,-79,40&locationReferencing=olr,shape,tmc&units=metric
```